# Consequences of Signing on a blank Paper

Tags: contracts, india, legal, law

What are the consequences of signing on a blank Rs1000 Non-Judicial Stamp paper?

What worst could happen?

Comment: More than likely, they get to do whatever they want to you.

Which, as your solicitor will explain, you will RICHLY deserve for signing a blank sheet of paper before at least running it past him.

See a solicitor (attorney) NOW.  ***BEFORE YOU SIGN IT.***

Comment: What is the context? Who has asked you to sign? Why do they want you to sign?

Comment: Actually My father has Taken money from someone and he had signed on blank 1000 rupees Non judicial Stamp paper, Now it's  worrying me,what should I do next?

Comment: Seems like a question for law.stackexchange.com or money.stackexchange.com

Comment: the classic old fax fraud scam...

Comment: @FarooqueAbdullah get it back as soon as you can.

Comment: Let me ask you this: what's the best that can happen? Why would you do this?

Answer (score 10):

The exact type of paper doesn't matter a huge deal here, but **never ever sign a blank piece of paper.**

A signed blank piece of paper can be used to fabricate any sort of contract. It could be used to 'resign' from your position of employment. It could be used to fake a murder confession. It could be used as a sort of identity fraud.

There is nothing good that can come of signing this blank piece of paper and an almost endless list of bad things that could happen. Who ever is asking you to do this likely has malicious intent and should not be trusted.

Comment: I'm a little out of context here, but since we're talking about signing contracts, here's a friendly advice. We're in the year 2020, so always write the whole year when you're adding a date to a contract. If you write 24/02/20 for axample, someone might add a 17 to the end of the date and the contract will be considered as signed the 24/02/2017.

Comment: And I also recommend putting your initial on every page of a contract and have each page be numbered. This makes it a lot harder for someone to sneak something in later and pretend it was part of the original agreement.

Comment: Numbered: Not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 but 1 out of 5, 2 out of 5, 3 out of 5 etc. And strike through empty space on the paper.